# Background check problem - mismatched previous employment dates

Tags: job-offer, background-check

I got a conditional job offer (pending background check).

My resume stated I worked for a company from Sept 2007 - Jan 2010. 
But, I worked for them from Sept 2007 - April 2009, and from Sept 2009 to Jan 2010. I decided to leave (quit my job) and travel. After 4 months and getting back, they again hired me in the same position.

On my references of each company, I gave them phone number of the Director (company's number with extension), but during background check they called the HR dept. and that's where the discrepancy happened.

I have been told that they are unable to verify my employment on those 4 months
and is asking me proof.

The company uses 3rd party for Background check and I spoke with them and they only verify employment record by talking to HR and won't accept anything else.

Any advise how to tackle this issue?

Edit: 
I have looked at the following question, and it doesn't address my problem:
[Issue with background-check on previous employment start-date](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12259/issue-with-background-check-on-previous-employment-start-date)

Comment: No, my question is very different.

Comment: I don't see any non-trivial differences. Please explain why you think it is different.

Comment: @Fandi1 Yes, your question is a duplicate. In particular, the first sentence of the answer to the other question "_Yes. Tell them._" is also the answer to your question, in my opinion. Just tell them what you tell us.

Comment: Simply tell the new employer that you took 4 months of unpaid leave in order to travel?

Comment: @Cronax Qutting and being rehired is not the same as unpaid leave. For one thing, if an employee requests unpaid leave the employer can refuse. They can't prevent an employee from quitting.