# Listed wrong date in resume

Tags: resume, start-date

I started a job in 2013, but mistakenly put the start year down as 2014 in my resume. If anything, it makes my gig looks shorter. In general, would this be a problem for background check?

Comment: People make mistakes. Contact the folks who have that copy of the resume, apologise for not catching the error sooner,  and give them the correction.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone contacts you with the old resume, assuming you are tracking where you sent your resume, let them know of the minor error at that time.  It should not be a big deal if your qualifications match what they are looking for especially since this error appears to be in your favor.

I would not call them up and say I made a mistake until it becomes important to do so.

It goes without saying to correct the mistake on your resume ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should we honest. Better reedit it and check everything clearly. You should ask someone to help check. Contact them and ask whether you should send a new edited resume. Be quick!

Read this your more and other ideas.

1. [issue-with-background-check-on-previous-employment-start-date](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12259/issue-with-background-check-on-previous-employment-start-date)
2. [What happens if the dates of employment on your resume/interviews do not match up with the dates on your background check?](https://www.quora.com/What-happens-if-the-dates-of-employment-on-your-resume-interviews-do-not-match-up-with-the-dates-on-your-background-check)

Good luck to you.