# Date disparity on resume before background check

Tags: resume, background-check

I've been offered, and have accepted a job at a large tech company. The next step is the background check where, among other things, they'll be verifying previous job titles and dates employed.

I noticed on my resume I accidentally stated an end date of 2 months after my actual end date (Mar 2019 vs Jan 2019). In total, I was with the employer for 5 years. How severe a mistake is this? Enough to rescind the offer?

*Note: all other information is completely accurate, and all other areas of the background check should come out clean. All references should be highly favorable.*

Comment: Related duplicate: [Listed wrong date in resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/82896/listed-wrong-date-in-resume)

Comment: I agree there are similarities between the topics, but I consider this unique since a 2-month disparity is far different from a 1-year disparity.

Comment: I also added an answer for you to consider

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How severe a mistake is this? Enough to rescind the offer?

Giving or taking 2 months compared to 5 years is few time.

However, **I suggest you admit your mistake**. Reach out to your company and explain to them about the typo, so they are aware of it in case it's found out.

This will save your chances in case +- 2 months is something "enough to rescind the offer" for them.

Comment: Exactly. As with many questions on Workplace, the answer is "talk to somebody about it."