# I filled out different employment dates in background check form after receiving offer than that listed in resume?

Tags: job-offer, hiring-process, background-check

I received a Job Offer from company A, which is contingent upon background check. Resume they have says that I have been working for company B since 2007.

In 2015, I did not get my work visa in US and so my CEO asked me to work remotely from India(home country) as a consultant/contractor till I get my Green Card and I moved to India in May 2015.  They just sort of have been keeping me on till I waited for my Green Card to come back. My boss is the CEO of the company, which is very large and there is no way I can ask him to generate any proof about me working in India for that period, let alone tell him I am leaving.

I got back in Dec 2016 and applied to company A and went through all the rounds of interviews with a resume that states I am still working at company B. In my interview, I mentioned to the Hiring Manager that I have been in India since 2015 but I never mentioned that I have been working as a consultant since 2015.

They sent me the background check application last week through a 3rd party named FADV. Before filling out the application I called company B's US office HR and they told me in their system I have last date till May 2015 so I filled out the application stating that my employment with the company B ended in May 2015.

I haven't really lied anywhere but I am afraid that **if they compare my resume on the file against the background check application**, they will see that my employment dates for company B are mismatched. Otherwise my background check will come clean for sure because of the correct dates on it.

Should I A) just pray that they do not compare my resume with the background check application form or B) let them know upfront before results come back about what is going on in case they do compare resume with background application or C) Just wait for the results and if they do notice the difference in resume, tell them honestly what is going on?!

I don't know how to significantly prove I have been in India working for them.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: ["Issue with background-check on previous employment start-date"](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12259/issue-with-background-check-on-previous-employment-start-date)

Comment: @DavidK I saw that question. It is related but is a bit different. I did not make a mistake on the employment dates on the resume as mentioned in that question. I just want to know how to explain me still working for the company as a consultant when my HR shows employment termination in 2015.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldnt worry to much about it.  You were not trying to deceive the company. They have already decided to offer you the position, and are going through the expense of that process.

If anyone notices the difference you can explain easily enough that you are still working for Company B just as a consultant not as an employee.  Your resume accurately reflects your work history not your employment history.  I have a similar issue.  I have been consulting for 20 years now, and at various times been forced to switch employers to continue work at a company I was contracted to.  My resume does not list my employer for these positions, rather the company I was consulting with.  People understand the realities of business, and the ones that are less forgiving were never going to hire you in the first place.

Comment: Yes. Maybe things are different in India or with this particular company. But in general, the point of a background check is to see if you're blatantly lying -- saying you have 20 years experience when really you've never done this job before, etc. If they notice a discrepancy in dates they might ask you to explain, but normally they're not going to rescind a job offer over something like that. There are lots of reasons for minor discrepancies, from your case -- contractor versus employee -- to somebody made a mistake to, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Company is legit with $400 million in revenues so that is not a problem. I was a special case. When I did not get my visa, they wanted me to stay on the team and continue working till I got my Green card and then I would just come back.

Comment: @manutdfan - I just mean that some companies red flag applicants that have too many employers.  Its kind of an out dated practice as times have changed and there is no real expectation of company loyalty any more.  But there are some companies (mostly small still family owned) that have not updated their practices and still value that company loyalty.  A candidate with significant time as a  consultant has little if any chance of ever getting hired on at one of these companies unless they know someone.

Comment: Thanks @IDrinkandIKnowThings. Really appreciate it. I am going to run with it and if they compare my resume with background check form and then ask me why I filled different dates, I'll just tell then what the deal is.