# I graduated over 20 years ago and put the wrong graduation date on my background check

Tags: background-check

The background check revealed that I put the incorrect graduation date for my bachelors degree that I got over 20 years ago. It was an honest mistake, actually put a date later than the actual graduation date. I do not have a copy of my diploma and when filling out the background check tried to think back when I graduated by relating it to where I worked. Will the company rescind my offer?

Comment: Only the company can answer this question, but you can ask yourself: "Does changing this information make my CV look more attractive to employers?". If not, chances are high that everything will be fine and no one will think you did this on purpose. Nobody cares if you graduated in 2000 or 2001.

Comment: You mean the particular day of a month of a year? Exceptionally few will care about the particular day in any case.

Comment: The dates were not listed on my resume, I only put the incorrect dates on the HireRight background check questionnaire

Comment: No it was the year of graduation I put 1989 and it was actually 1986

Comment: It was for my undergrad degree. I went on to graduate school 10 years later, had the diploma so it was easy to remember the dates and year I graduated with an MBA

Comment: Transposing a 9 for a 6 is such a common error, I can't imagine anyone would think anything of it. Worst case scenario would be they ask you about it, at which point you tell them it was an honest mistake.

Comment: It *might* be an issue if you're applying for a security clearance and they think you lied deliberately. They take lies on the security clearance paperwork really seriously.

Comment: @Pam, this is not directed at you, but to us collectively. We have a serious problem with our hiring processes if a person is worried about being mistaken about the date of an event that happened more then 30 years ago. How we've gotten to the point where we fear the hiring process like we would fear a parole hearing is something desperately in need of fixing.

Comment: There are similar questions [Issue with background-check on previous employment start-date](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12259/issue-with-background-check-on-previous-employment-start-date)

Comment: @joeqwerty Fully agree, the amount of questions regarding this topic here on TWP and the questioneers sentiment towards possible negative background-checks due to some date mix-ups really indicates a problem in hiring processes and the weighing/importance of performed background-checks..

Comment: Putting a later date is not necessarily a good thing, that means there is a gap to be filled. Let's say you graduated in 2001 and then were 1 year in jail, you might be tempted to say you graduated in 2002...

Comment: @joeqwerty I think this is more a matter of a fear of idiots doing background checks and rejecting them over trivial errors.  I'm sure we have all had run-ins with idiots that apply zero common sense to what they're doing and reject if it's not perfect by their measure (and sometimes it's their measure that's at fault!)

Answer (score 6):

> Will the company rescind my offer?

Some companies are very pedantic with background checks but this is minor. Usually unless they have some other reason they will ask for clarification before anything else.

Chances are it won't even be mentioned, no one really cares what happened that far back except background checking companies who get paid to dig deep.