# Offer rescind for employment date discrepancy?

Tags: background-check

Before continuing, I just want to say that I acknowledge it's purely my error on this. Also, I am kind of freaking out over it and wished I had known better.

Recently I received a job offer and am going through pre-employment screening now. I previously had a job from Oct 2017 to Nov 22 2019. When I was updating my CV recently I recalled wrongly thinking I had finished the November month and put Oct 2017 - Dec 2019 instead. This was the CV that I used for the interview process, etc.

When doing the background check questionnaire, I had to update the exact date and requested for verification a letter from my past employer and found out that my last day was Nov 22 instead (with 16.5 days of unused leave that I got paid for if that matters - even though I don't think so. I just want to provide as much info as possible for advice here).

Will I "fail" the background check as a result / have my offer rescind? appreciate the advice from more experienced folks here thank you

Comment: Anecdotally, I have had 2 issues with background checks. One where I had made a mistake, one where the checkers made a mistake. In both cases they followed up with me and we resolved the problem inside 5 minutes. No rescinding involved.

Comment: I have been the subject of multiple extended background investigations for work. The important thing is to correct the information as soon as possible. Investigators understand that it's easy to get the exact dates of things wrong. Heck, I completely blanked  on two weeks of unemployment benefits I had collected a long time ago and left it completely off the form and it wasn't a problem. We just corrected it as soon as I remembered.

Comment: Does anyone really care if a job two years ago ended in November or December? If they thought you were good enough to be offered a job, rescinding for that reason would be plain idiotic.

Comment: Next to zero chance.  Besides, any employer who would fuss over 9 days isn't worth working for.

Comment: @gnasher729 It depends on the purpose of the investigation. If it’s for a security clearance, too many date discrepancies can be an indication of more serious issues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with background-check on previous employment start-date](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12259/issue-with-background-check-on-previous-employment-start-date)

Comment: You should immediately send them an email letting them know (I just realised that X actually finished end of Nov rather than beginning of Dec), just to be on the safe side. Then don’t worry about it, you’ll be fine.

Comment: ‍♂️ *"Let's just see, shall we?"*

Answer (score 5):

> Will I "fail" the background check as a result / have my offer rescind?

The discrepancy is two weeks out of a two year period so most likely you will not fail the background check for this specific issue.  It was an honest mistake that anyone could have made, just make sure that you doublecheck that all of the other information provided is as accurate as possible.

In the future, I would be more careful about the accuracy of the information you put on your resume.  Besides the issue of discrepancies for background checks, sloppy work on your resume does not look good for you as a potential candidate and some employers may view that as a reflection of your work ethic.

Comment: Yes, it's best to have a well made and factually correct CV from the start. Keep a copy and update it in future rather than create a new one from your head.

Comment: I have a list of important dates in a spreadsheet, including start and end dates of my employment history. This is useful for background checks and various clearances that government agencies/contractors require.

Answer (score 1):

> Will I "fail" the background check as a result / have my offer rescind? appreciate the advice from more experienced folks here thank you

**No**

Once I flipped start/end dates on two different jobs.  The HR rep doing my pre-employment screening caught it and called me.  She'd pulled tax records from both companies and noticed the difference.  I was embarrassed, and immediately put the correct dates in.  I worked at that company for 5 years.

For only a 2 week discrepancy, they likely won't even bother calling you.