# Wrong Qualification on my CV, Currently doing background check

Tags: resume, qualification, graduate

I'm a recent graduate with an Integrated Masters Degree in Computer Science. On my CV I have listed the qualification as two separate qualifications. A BSc in Computer Science and a MSc in Computer science. This was due to me misunderstanding an integrated Masters as I thought it was both a MSc and BSC.

I've currently just completed a background screening and am concerned this misunderstanding on my behalf will have my offer revoked. This is the first CV I've made since I graduated and displayed my qualification wrong due to a misunderstanding. Should I get in touch first to explain the situation or wait until they reach out? How do companies look down on these sort of discrepancies? I don't want to appear dishonest.

Comment: Very related (I'd say dupe): https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/12259/73791

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with background-check on previous employment start-date](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12259/issue-with-background-check-on-previous-employment-start-date)

Comment: What is your actual qualification? One thing to note is that integrated masters are often not considered an equal qualification to a BSc + MSc but rather a grade lower. This varies a lot though.

Comment: My Actual Qualification name is Masters of Computing (Honours) Computer Science with Artificial Intelligence. On my very first CV I have MSc Computer Science with Artificial Intelligence, and BSc Computer Science with Artificial Intelligence. The company recruited me based on my CV they found which is from September, but my more recent CVs have it down as MComp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are worried about a discrepancy, it's always better to get in front of it.  The company is going to be much happier to get an email from you saying "I just found out there may be an issue" than to have the background check company flag something.

Practically, it is doubtful that the company is going to care.  If you have a master's degree, no one is going to care whether you got a bachelor's degree at the same time or not.  The background check company may flag something if you filled out their form with two different degrees and they can only validate one.

Comment: I'll mark this as the Answer as things are progressing should be getting my firm offer in writing now.

Answer (score 5):

> Should I get in touch first to explain the situation

Yes.

For the rest we cannot predict the future or other people's actions. But being caught is almost universally worse than being upfront about a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue easily by forwarding the employer a copy of your Graduation Certificate that clarifies the situation.

I assume that you have listed the dates of your University attendance at the same time for both qualifications.

In some UK institutions, a BA or BSc is granted after 3 years and it is upgraded to MA or Msc the following year so it is a 2 part process. I imagine your situation is no different.

I cannot imagine an employer would disqualify you for putting your qualifications down slightly incorrect since after all you have proof you attended the institution for the period stated on your CV and the Certificate clarified the correct qualification.

Good luck in your new position.