# Seeking Guidance on Resume Discrepancies for Background Check Concerns

Tags: resume, job-offer, hiring-process, background-check

My situation is a bit intricate, so I thank you for taking the time to read through it.

Over the span of two years (from 2020 to 2022), I held various positions within the same company, transitioning from part-time to an internship and eventually to a full-time role (which was a return offer from the internship).

The issue arises from the fact that I interned at this company for two months, from February 2021 to March 2021, before transitioning to a full-time position from April 2021 to April 2022. Subsequently, in April 2022, I left the company to pursue a two-year Master's course, which is nearing completion. Recently, I secured a full-time offer at another company, which conducts background checks. In the process of revising my resume before submitting the job application, I removed the intern position, only retaining the full-time role. Moreover, I neglected to update the start date, resulting in my resume indicating that I began the full-time role at the start date of the internship.

Furthermore, I noticed a similar issue with one of the part-time jobs I held during university, where I mistakenly listed the end date on my resume one month earlier than the actual date.

I'm very concerned that this might be perceived as a pattern during the background check, potentially jeopardizing my offer. It's crucial to note that these alterations were inadvertent mistakes; I had no intention to deceive or gain any advantage. The decision to remove the intern position was simply to streamline my CV, as it was becoming overly lengthy.

Should I contact the recruiter and them know about this, or should I wait for them to bring it up incase they do. I don't know what to do, I'm very scared.

Edit: All is good! I contacted the hiring manager and he said it is fine and thanked me for bringing it up.

Comment: Reporting less experience than you really have is safer than reporting more...

Comment: Welcome to TWP Rayan :) please take the [tour] and read the [help/dont-ask] to start to familiarize yourself with this site.

Comment: That being said, your question has been asked before, and thus why some users and I tagged it as such. Please check the duplicate questions to find answers that will apply to your situation (all or most of them are "yes, reach out to them and correct your mistake").

Comment: (posting relevant/dupe links here again, as this post seems to have been reopened and the target dupes gone. I won't VTC here again but I'm sharing the links regardless so OP and others can benefit from it). Does this answer your question Rayan? https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/194103/wrong-qualification-on-my-cv-currently-doing-background-check and https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12259/issue-with-background-check-on-previous-employment-start-date

Comment: @DarkCygnus Thanks alot for all your help and the warm welcome. IYes! All the posts were helpful and I will be informing the hiring manager. Hopefully all turns out well, as I really do like this job.

Comment: Nobody is really going care about a 2 month internship or a part time job, I assume the part time job, has nothing to do with the work you would do for the company if you were to be hired.

Answer (score 0):

You stated that the matter has solved itself as you contacted the hiring manager and discussed the concerns.

In general:

- The content, order and level of clarity of a CV depends on the
  region, company, culture, industry and position you are applying for.
- An entry job level in the free market is not as strict about CV content than eg. applying for a role as a judge in a higher court.
- When in doubt contact the hiring person and ask what level of clarity you should provide in your CV without overloading with information.